# JPA 2.0 + One to One + Shared Primary Key not being set

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, one-to-one, hibernate-4.x

Have to two tables Customer and Upload, where I track the number of items the customer has uploaded.  It is a one to one relationship with a shared primary key `CustomerID`, which is a unique identifier. I am struggling trying to get the save to work. I am using Hibernates uuid2 strategy to handle the creation/saving of the unique identifiers.  Before I included the Upload entity, Customer would save correctly with a uuid.  Basically I want the upload to be created whenever someone makes a customer object.

**Customer:**

```java
@Entity
public class Upload implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="UPLOADCOUNT",    nullable=true,  unique=false)
    private Integer uploadCount = new Integer(0); 

    @MapsId ("CUSTOMERID")
    @OneToOne (optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMERID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMERID", nullable=false,  unique=true ) 
    private Customer customer;  

    @Id 
    @Column(name="CUSTOMERID", length=36, nullable=false, unique=true, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String customerId_;

     public Upload(Customer customer) {    
         this.customer = customer;
     }
}
```

**Upload:**

```java
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMERID", unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String customerId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Upload upload ; 


    public Customer() {
        this.upload = new Upload(this);        
    }
}
```

**Code to save:**

```java
Customer customer = new Customer();
EntityManager em = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();
EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();

trans.begin();
em.persist(customer);
trans.commit();
```

**Exception:**

```java
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): Upload
```

Comment: in your "save" code : what is `entity` ?

Comment: it is customer.  I have updated the code

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `@JoinColumn` you can try this:

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUSTOMERID", referencedColumnName="CUSTOMERID")
```

more details [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Example_OneToOne_id_annotation)

Or an another possible solution: update your `Upload` class like this.

```
@Id 
@Column(name="CUSTOMERID", length=36, nullable=false, unique=true, insertable=false, updatable=false)
@GeneratedValue(generator=”foreign”) 
@GenericGenerator(name=”foreign”, strategy = “foreign”, parameters =    {@Parameter(name=”property”, value=”customer”)})
private String customerId_;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I get the same error still.

Comment: @Nadin just edited my post with another possible solution (using hibernate specific stuff)

Comment: Same result.  I would have thought this is a common case.

Answer (score 0):

### The important thing to create self-generated UUID related entities is to set the UUID to a value of null.

If we hardcode the uuid, for example, a UUID.randomUUID () we will get an fk error similar to `PSQLException: null value in column "second_table_uuid" violates not-null constraint`

When creating the objects, make sure that the default value of the constructor of the related entities has null. If it is an entity A that contains B, it would only be necessary the null in the uuid of B and not of A. But just in case you can put null to all the UUIDs unless you already know the fk.

The other important thing is to use `@JoinColumn` instead of `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`, this would also generate the error.

I attach a snippet of my code which I made work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
data class Parent(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "parent_uuid")
        val parentUUID: UUID? = null,

        @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JoinColumn(name = "child_uuid", referencedColumnName = "child_uuid")
        var child: Child
) {
        constructor() : this(child = Child())
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
data class Child(
        @Id 
        @GeneratedValue 
        @Column(name = "child_uuid") 
        val childUUID: UUID? = null,
    
        @Column(name = "name") 
        val name: String,
) {
        constructor() : this(name = "")
}
```

And the compositions would be left with implicit null values in the UUIDs.

```
val child = Child(name = "test")
val parent = Parent(child = child)
```

GL